# Cisco 7962 cable unpluged with POE

Tags: voip

I've got a collection of CISCO 7962 IP phones powered by POE.  On some of them I plug them in to our POE switch and I get an error that the Ethernet cable is unplugged.  That strikes me as strange seeing as the power comes from the switch it's not attached to.

The phones are brand new.  I have several that are doing this on the network but not all.

Switch is pretty well used.

Thoughts and suggestions are appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would check layer one, the physical layer.  Although you have power to the device your wiring could have an issue.  Also verify that the switch ports are not causing the problem by connecting the phones to a known good port where you currently have a working device connected.  Alternatively you could connect the phones directly to the switch with a short patch cable to test questionable ports and bypass the existing wiring altogether.  This should give you an idea of where the problem exists.

Comment: I fixed this a while ago by recrimping the cable at the user end.  I didn't update the question, but your absolutely correct on your answer.